# Changes are not applied to the blade page after the deployment

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, laravel-blade, cloudflare

There is an AWS EC2 instance on which the laravel application is deployed. Cloudflare is also connected to it. I pushed the simplest change for the blade page, which changes the color of the title, but the page has not changed in any way and looks the same.
I am sure that the changes got to the server, connected via ssh and manually looked at the blade file.

I've tried the artisan commands `cache:clear`, `view:clear`, `config:clear`. I manually cleaned the `storage/framework/views` and `bootstrap/cache/` folders.
I was deleting the cloudflare cache and switched to developer mode.
None of this helped.

What other cache cleanup options did I miss?

Comment: Did you try clearing your browser cache?

Comment: CloudFlare is a CDN and CDNs tend to aggressively cache results on their end so when you need to deploy changes to an app behind a CDN you should also incorporate some way to invalidate those caches as well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in CloudFlare Rocket Loader. Everything worked after I turned it off.